# Any possibility to read the list of nunit tests triggered for execution in OneTimeSetup method

Tags: c#, nunit

I need to read the list of tests in OneTimeSetup method which are going to be executed. For example, I have a test class with 5 tests and I am going to run only two tests and when it comes to OneTimeSetup I just need the two tests name. Based on the list I will be doing project specific actions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This may be possible with reflection, but why exactly do you not want to run all unit tests? All tests should be isolated such that they can run without effecting the tests that run after them, meaning, you should be able run all unit tests in one run

Comment: This is for UI Automation tests. There is a huge wait time required for us after performing the prerequisite step. So instead of doing the test prerequisite in SetUp method we are finding a way to execute prerequisite for all tests in OneTimeSetup. And we might not require all tests to be executed everytime.

Comment: I am able to get all the tests using reflection. Any help to find the only tests which are scheduled for execution would be helpful for me ?

Comment: I am assuming you used the Type.GetMethods() method, meaning you now have an array `MethodInfo[]`. You can use `Array.Find<T>()`, or Linq's `.Where()` to grab specific MethodInfo objects out from it. But sadly I do not know how to setup a dynamic order of tests to be run based on external/ENV factors. The only way I know how to manually trigger tests is to use the IDE's GUI tools to run individual or groups of tests. The `dotnet test` [command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test) is going to be running the entire test project

Comment: I was able to filter the tests programmatically using the categories passed from command line and I was using the nunit console runner. I read the categories passed from command and compared that with the categories mentioned for tests with few logical loops.

Comment: Now I am supposed to execute the test using VSTest runner. Here i was not able to read the command line arguments which has the category filters. I also have doubt whether OneTimeSetup method is supported by vstest runner as it doesnot execute any console.writeline in it. Any suggestions on this issue ?

Comment: Console.WriteLine() generally does not work with all testing tools, but nUnit's classic assertions typically have overloads that take a string argument which will be piped to the console or testing tool GUI being used. So most simply, `Assert.Pass("message");` or `Assert.Fail("message")`, but even things like `Assert.AreEqual(actual, expected, $"FAIL {actual.ToString()} is not {expected.ToString()}");` which will print the string on failure